# Creative Commons License style

Tags: hyperlink, creative-commons

i generated a creative commons license for my website, they gave me a code to put into my website html.

The code is somenthing like:

```
<a href="tolicense">creative bla bla <img src="creative.icon bla bla"/></a>
```

I was wondering, is it possible to style it cause it's just a link targeting to the license page or should i leave it as it is for legal reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can style the link to match your own website style no problem at all, all they care about is that you are honoring the license by crediting the original authors of whatever has been created.

Comment: honoring how? linking to the creative common license page right? the link they gave me.. but i can put only the icon with link right?

Answer (score 1):

The link is only for the convenience of people who want to know more about the license. There is no legal reason to leave it as it is. You don't even have to include it, if you really don't want to.

bybe was assuming that you were sharing someone else's content using CC. If you are using this license for your own content, then that answer doesn't apply.